# Why does this integral $ \chi \int_0^a t^k \hat{f}(-tg)dt,$ converges?

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

Let $f$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support and let $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a smooth function wich vanishes on a set $A$. We consider another smooth functions $ \chi$ wich vanishes on the set $A$.

My question does the following function converge when $a \rightarrow + \infty$

$$ \chi \int_0^a t^k \hat{f}(-tg)dt,$$

Where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ ?

Comment: Is $\chi$ multiplying the integral? Also what does $\hat{f}(-tg)$ mean? the argument inside parentheses is a scalar, but $\hat{f}$ should take points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as inputs.

Comment: @Jose27, yes $chi$ multiply the integral and $g$ is a function! I asked this question when I red the proof of Lemma 106 (page 68) in the lecture notes called " Lecture notes on Equivariant cohomology " by matvei Libine.

Comment: If $g$ is  a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then does this integral converge ?

Comment: Sure, at least if $g\neq 0$ and $k\geq 0$ then the integral converges since $\hat{f}$ is a Schwartz function.

Comment: Thanks @Jose27 for your reply! I understand your point! But I still don't understand something: in the Lecture notes of matvei Libine, in his proof ( that a similar integral converges) he uses the function $chi$ which he assumed to vanish in the set A, the use of the function $chi$ was important in his proof. Could you say something about this please ?